# bulk product images uploading fails

Tags: import, magento-2.2.5, importexport

[image: CSV for product image uploading]

I am trying to bulk upload **images** for **products**
I am getting the following error:

> imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external
>   resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1

The product uploading works fine via csv but images are not uploading via csv. I have attached an image for reference. there are total 56 products.

I have removed `pub/media/import` from the **csv** as well but that didn't make a difference, the folder permission is 711, the magento version is 2.2.5

Comment: Have you tried uploading actual images to your server? I mean when you want to import products you have to manually upload images on correct path.

Comment: They are uploaded to pub/media/import when Im uploading this file. Can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I mean the same, so image files are there. I guess you can ignore this csv error and then try to reindex:indexer and flush:cache.

Comment: Okay, i'll try it out.

Comment: Why don't you try with Magmi?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. In my case the images where located outside the magento root (symlinked). Since Magento 2.1.14 *validatePath()* is called in

```
module-catalog-import-export/⁨Model/⁨Import⁩/Uploader.php->setTmpDir()
```

This is why importing images from a symlinked directory does not work any more. Moving the images into the magento root was the solution in my case.

Comment: Yep and I removed the pub/media/import and worked after that